# Add Datagridview Rows to Datatable when Checkbox is Checked in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable

i am working with Desktop Application and i am trying to create a datatable from a datagridview. but i only want to add those rows when checkbox is selected or checked. currently i created a datatable from a whole datagridview like this.

```
DataTable tbl = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource;
```

I have added a checkbox coloumn inside datagridview.. so please guide me how to add selected rows to a new datatable

Thanks.. Here is the new code Update

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (Convert.ToBoolean(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value) == true)
                    {
                        DataRow dr0 = tbl.NewRow();
                        dr0["ID"] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["ID"].Value;
                        dr0["BikeCC"] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["BikeCC"].Value.ToString();
                        dr0["ChassisModel"] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["ChassisModel"].Value.ToString();
                        dr0["BikeCC"] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["BikeCC"].Value.ToString();
                        dr0["ChassisModel"] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Chassismodel"].Value.ToString();
                        tbl.Rows.Add(dr0);

                    }
                }

                objMdl.RecordTable = tbl;
```

This is the way i could find to add selected rows into a new datatable... it is lenghty but i am still facing little issues. which i will post in a bit for your look.

Comment: Add Event datagridview_DataError

Comment: And your code works now? In fact your code is some kind of `traditional`, it's of course lengthy, however you can still use `ImportRow` to copy the row instead of assigning cells yourself.

Comment: Yes, it does do the required job, but additionally it is adding copy of all rows to the data grid.. do i have to clear the datatable each time??

Comment: remember to init `tbl` as `((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).Clone` and check the condition in `if-statement`, I doubt it's `true` in all the loops.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help and time.. yes .Clone did work.. it is solved now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your checkbox column is named *yourCheckBoxColumn*:

```
DataTable tbl = ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).Clone();//Clone structure first
var rows = dataGridView1.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
                        .Where(r=>Convert.ToBoolean(r.Cells["yourCheckBoxColumn"].Value))
                        .Select(r=>((DataRowView)r.DataBoundItem).Row);
foreach(var row in rows)
   tbl.ImportRow(row);
```

Comment: Problem when i type in my check box column.. it gives error that column does not belong to table tbl.

Comment: Why do you type in `CheckBoxColumn`? it's for `mouse interaction`, anyway I still don't get what your problem is now.

Comment: my Checkbox column name is check when i type "Check" for the column name it doesnt find this name inside the datagrid.

Comment: @RanaDotnet `check` or `Check`? the case-sensitivity is important. Could you show the code to add your checkbox column?

Comment: and when i give index of the column, i get error saying Specific cast is not valid.

Comment: This is the code i am trying. before your edit was made.
            DataTable tbl = ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).AsEnumerable()
                 .Where(r => r.Field<bool>("Check"))
                 .CopyToDataTable();

Comment: @RanaDotnet that code is old, my code now is not that, please check it again.

Comment: i have tried that aswell see the picture i added in answer box

Comment: @RanaDotnet where is the picture? you should update it in your question, not in your answer.

Comment: @RanaDotnet looks like you use `VS 2005` or below? `OfType` is supported since `VS 2008`.

Comment: @RanaDotnet what is the error message? I tested it on `VS 2008` and it compiles OK, that's strange.

Comment: @RanaDotnet you should try running it, **VS 2010** has some bugs on `formatting`, it underlines many things but in fact, there isn't any problem, just try running it.

Comment: NO Mate still no joy. could you show me the assemblies list you have in vs2008 for this file?

Comment: Exact Error is 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection' does not contain a definition for 'OfType' and no extension method 'OfType' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)'

Comment: @RanaDotnet is your code added with `using System.Linq;` although that's added by default.

Comment: i deleted the exe and rebuilt the whole project and the error is gone thanks.. but now the old error is back saying Specified cast is not valid... arghhhhh!! sorry for being a pain.

Comment: @RanaDotnet at which line it complains?

Comment: it complain on this one foreach(var row in rows)
   tbl.ImportRow(row);

Comment: @RanaDotnet if it complains another error, I can try digging more on this but it can't be like as you said, the type of `row` in the `foreach` is in fact `DataRow`, I have no idea on why it complains so.

Comment: I have updated my questions please have a look. i have updated it with a possible answer.. which is lengthy but i am still learning.